# How to overcome SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' code can't decode bytes error in a string variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable `log_message = "Your file name is C:\Users\MEMEME\test.txt"` and I would like to lowercase it before doing some extra processing. But as soon as declare that variable, I get the `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' code can't decode bytes` error at character \U. I know \U represents unicode encoding and I cannot control this variable because its coming from a caller so I have to do any processing (escaping or raw string conversion) once I receive it.

I have seen solutions to send it as raw string (r'') but this variable will be coming from a caller so I had to convert when it arrives so anything involves r'' (i.e., r'{}'.format() etc.,) will not be an option. I tried repr() method which didn't work either.

I am going in circles and most answers leading me to r'' solution only. It seemed trivial to solve but not anymore. Please can someone help?

Thanks

My code:

```
def test_my_string(test_string: str):
    result = test_string.lower()
    return result
log_message = "Your file name is C:\Users\MEMEME\test.txt"
test_my_string(log_message)
```

when I run this I get an error at the line where I had log_message. The error is: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position' (it fails at \U)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding r in front of the string solves this problem. You can also solve these kind of problems, by changing single-backslash(\) to double-backslashes(\\) or single-slash (/)

```
def test_my_string(test_string: str):
result = test_string.lower()
return result
log_message = r"Your file name is 
C:\Users\MEMEME\test.txt"
test_my_string(log_message)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @jhyun-ahn, thanks for the answer however I have mentioned it in my question that I have already explored the r'' string option and looking for alternatives if any available.

Comment: I apologize of bad solution.  it seems that \U error is done in fundamental level in python. Can you split your code files? make that message to some txt file, replace single backslash to others, then import that string. (you have to deal it before computer get input string with \U, before Line#4 of your code)